# PowerShell v2.0 DNS Server Search Order Modification

Tags: powershell, dns

I'm extremely new to scripting, but i'll explain what I want to do.
I want to dynamically add my dns server to my coworkers machines.  I need to figure out how to do this.  Our VPN resets the dns server list every time we vpn in.  Once inside I can change the settings but that's annoying.  I want to create a script that will

1. Read current DNS servers, and store them into an array
2. Determine if the DNS server, that I am attempting to add, is already in the array
3. Modify the array into a correct order (ie. put mine first, the rest don't matter, and then add in 8.8.8.8)
4. Set the DNS servers to the array

I will be doing this for search order as well, but I think that once I'm able to get this answered I can move on.

I was looking at this article to help set the DNS server search order, however it doesnt have any information on how to view them.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings.aspx

I'm confident that I can modify and set the DNS server IP addresses, once I can get it to read current status and populate a variable.

I tried to follow that and then use it to read the dns server search order and populate a variable but it didn't seem to like it. This library says that there is `DNSServerSearchOrder`, but I have been unable to get anything to save to a variable.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx

I tried to do this in VBS and I had some issues with resizing the array once I set it.  I took this from someone else's script that just displayed the DNS servers.  I'm just trying to manipulate the variable to reorder in this, however it doesn't work correctly.  I was hoping PowerShell would make it easier to modify arrays.

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
sithDomain = "sith.empire.com"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colNicConfigs = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")

For Each objNicConfig In colNicConfigs
  DIM strDNSSuffixSO(1) 
  strDNSServerSO = ""
  strDNSHostName = objNicConfig.DNSHostName
  strIndex = objNicConfig.Index
  strDescription = objNicConfig.Description
  strDNSDomain = objNicConfig.DNSDomain
  If Not IsNull(objNicConfig.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder) Then
    For Each strDNSSuffix In objNicConfig.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder
      ReDim Preserve strDNSSuffixSO(UBound(strDNSSuffixSO) + 1) 
      strDNSSuffixSO(UBound(strDNSSuffixSO)) = strDNSSuffix
    Next
  End If

i=0
sithFound = False
'Wscript.echo sithFound
For Each strDNSSuffix In strDNSSuffixSO
    If strDNSSuffix = sithDomain Then
        strDNSSuffixSO(i) = strDNSSuffixSO(0)
        strDNSSuffixSO(0) = sithDomain
        sithFound = True
    End If
    i = i+1
Next
If sithFound = False Then
    ReDim Preserve strDNSSuffixSO(UBound(strDNSSuffixSO) + 1) 
    strDNSSuffixSO(UBound(strDNSSuffixSO)) = strDNSSuffixSO(0)
    strDNSSuffixSO(0) = sithDomain
    End If


  strDNSServerSO = ""
  If Not IsNull(objNicConfig.DNSServerSearchOrder) Then
    For Each strDNSServer In objNicConfig.DNSServerSearchOrder
      strDNSServerSO = strDNSServerSO & VbCrLf & String(37, " ") & _
 strDNSServer
    Next
  End If
  strDomainDNSRegistrationEnabled = _
 objNicConfig.DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled
  strFullDNSRegistrationEnabled = objNicConfig.FullDNSRegistrationEnabled
  strDNSSettings = strDNSSettings & VbCrLf & VbCrLf & _
   "  Network Adapter " & strIndex & VbCrLf & _
   "    DNS Domain Suffix Search Order:" & strDNSSuffixSO(0) & strDNSSuffixSO(1) '& strDNSSuffixSO(2) & VbCrLf '& _
   REM "    DNS Server Search Order:" & strDNSServerSO & VbCrLf 
   REM "    Domain DNS Registration Enabled: " & _
   REM strDomainDNSRegistrationEnabled & VbCrLf & _
   REM "    Full DNS Registration Enabled:   " & _
   REM strFullDNSRegistrationEnabled
Next

WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "DNS Settings" & VbCrLf & VbCrLf & _
 "Host Name: " & strDNSHostName & strDNSSettings & VbCrLf & sithFound
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. See in-line documentation / comments for further information.

```
# 1. Get all instances of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI class
#    that are "IPEnabled"
$NetAdapterConf = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IpEnabled = 'true' and Description like '%centrino%'";

# 2. Declare an array of DNS servers to configure
$DnsServerArray = '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4';

# 3. For each instance of Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration, call the
#    SetDNSServerSearchOrder WMI method, passing in the array of DNS
#    servers as the one and only parameter. We also append the existing
#    DNS servers, so as not to override them completely.
foreach ($NetAdapterConf in $NetAdapterConfList) {
    $NetAdapterConf.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(($DnsServerArray + $NetAdapterConf.DNSServerSearchOrder));
}
```

It's a pretty simple script, and will simply configure the DNS server search order to be whatever you specify in the `$DnsServerArray` variable (which is an `Array` of `String` objects).

**Edit**: Modified the script to also include the user's existing DNS servers.